# Big Query tables text data upload issue

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was trying to load the data from dataframe into big query tables. It has loaded only integer data type fields but not the text data type. Could anyone help me to resolve this?

```
dataset\_id = 'Baxter\_Raw\_Import'

\# The project defaults to the Client's project if not specified.

dataset = client.get\_dataset(dataset\_id) # API request

table\_ref = dataset.table('Text\_Raw\_Files\_Table')

job\_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(autodetect=True,schema=schema,encoding="UTF8")

job = client.load\_table\_from\_dataframe(

Old\_Data,

"Baxter\_Raw\_Import.Text\_Raw\_Files\_Table",

location='US',# Must match the destination dataset location.

job\_config=job\_config) # API request

job.result() # Waits for table load to complete.

print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(

job.output\_rows, dataset\_id, table\_ref.path))

&#x200B;

 

schema = \[bigquery.SchemaField("Complaint\_PR", "INTEGER"),

bigquery.SchemaField("PR", "INTEGER"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Event Description", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Sample Analysis Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Manufacturing Record Review Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Cybersecurity Investigation Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Complaint Evaluation Conclusion Summary", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Nonconformance Rationale", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Labeling Evaluation\_OR\_Assessment Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Distribution Shipping Investigation Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Design Investigation Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Other Evaluation\_OR\_Review Results", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField("Complaint Receipt Date", "DATE")\]
```

I have tried uploaded the data using Insert in query it was worked but when i try to upload from dataframe in google client big query. it loaded only integer fields not the string even after clearly mentioned the schema